# How to bypass Cross-Origin Request Blocked CORS request did not succeed in this script?

Tags: php, ajax, cross-origin-read-blocking

On my local machine all Ajax requests work just fine and the app works perfectly. It is a different story on the host machine. When trying to execute below Ajax script I get :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I spent all day trying to fix this error to no avail. I even added this in the head of every page

```
  <?php ob_start(); 
       header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
       ?>
```

I read about [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) and I'm wondering how to implement this solution?

This is the *short* version of the Ajax

```
       $( ".submit-signup-form" ).click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       if(formvalues!==''){
       $("#sign-up-form-2").submit(

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'queries/register.php',
           data: formvalues,
           success: function(customerarr){ //callback}
      })
      })

     });
}
```

When debugging the app in the console I tried `console.log(formvalues)` and everything printed out okay. The form does get ALL the variables so I'm not understanding how to make the script work on live host.

Comment: The error you're describing sounds like it's coming from an ad provider, not from your web page.

Comment: Today I have the exact same thing happening to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in ajax request...

```
dataType: 'jsonp',  //use jsonp data type in order to perform cross domain ajax
  crossDomain: true,
```